# Qual o RegExp para validar matrículas de Portugal

Tags: regex

Queria saber qual é a [Expressão Regular](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express%C3%A3o_regular) que valida matrículas de Portugal.

Considerando que em Portugal há este tipo de matrículas

- AA-00-00
- 00-00-AA
- 00-AA-00
- AA-00-AA

qual o código de RegExp que tenho de usar para validar num formulário apenas matrículas desse tipo?

```
<input id="matrícula" type="text">
```

Comment: @Maniero porque motivo fechou o tópico?

Comment: Porque não respondemos perguntas que dão um enunciado e fica esperando que façam o código para si. As perguntas devem ser só conceitual ou então ter um problema específico. Isto é o que se chama enunciado, ou faça pra mim. Não faz sentido fechar quando uma pessoa pergunta e manter aberto quando a pessoa pergunta e responde.

Comment: @Maniero certo, mas excusava de dar um ponto negativo. Eu fiz a pergunta e respondi pois achava que esta questão era relevante e queria partilhar as conclusões a que cheguei.

Comment: Eu não dei negativo, só fechei.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com a [wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matr%C3%ADculas_de_autom%C3%B3veis_em_Portugal)

> Inicialmente a sequência utilizada era a AA-00-00. Em 1992 passou-se para a 00-00-AA e, em 2005, para a 00-AA-00 que está actualmente em vigor. Quando esta chegar ao fim, está prevista a introdução da sequência AA-00-AA.

Ou seja, consideramos os quatro formatos válidos

- AA-00-00
- 00-00-AA
- 00-AA-00
- AA-00-AA

Basta apenas agora considerar a expressão regular seguinte que considera exatamente estes 4 casos válidos, com um hífen comum (-) a separar os dígitos

```regex
/^(([A-Z]{2}-\d{2}-(\d{2}|[A-Z]{2}))|(\d{2}-(\d{2}-[A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]{2}-\d{2})))$/
```

Tem aqui um exemplo que pode usar

```js
$("#matricula").css('outline','none').on('input', function(e){
  e.preventDefault()

  var expr = /^(([A-Z]{2}-\d{2}-(\d{2}|[A-Z]{2}))|(\d{2}-(\d{2}-[A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]{2}-\d{2})))$/

  if (!expr.test($(this).val())){
    $(this).css('border', '2px solid red')
  } else {
    $(this).css('border', '2px solid green')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Insira a matrícula, usando o hífen comum (-) entre os dígitos:<br>
<input id="matricula" type="text">
```

Comment: Sugiro colocar o `^` no início, caso contrário a regex aceitará valores como "AAA-00-AA". Além disso, dá pra simplificar um pouco: `\d` equivale a `[0-9]` e dá pra agrupar alguns casos (se começa com letras, sempre tem 2 números depois e no final 2 números ou letras, ou seja, `[A-Z]{2}-\d{2}-(\d|[A-Z]){2})`). E se começa com números, o restante é 2 números e 2 letras **ou** 2 letras e 2 números (ou seja, `\d{2}-(\d{2}-[A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]{2}-\d{2})`). Então a regex ficaria `^(([A-Z]{2}-\d{2}-(\d|[A-Z]){2})|(\d{2}-(\d{2}-[A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]{2}-\d{2})))$` - [veja](https://regex101.com/r/0eqtXE/2/)

Comment: Correção, no primeiro caso (começa com letras), seria `[A-Z]{2}-\d{2}-(\d{2}|[A-Z]{2})` (a versão do comentário anterior aceitava um número e uma letra no final, agora aceita somente 2 números ou 2 letras). Então a regex fica `^(([A-Z]{2}-\d{2}-(\d{2}|[A-Z]{2}))|(\d{2}-(\d{2}-[A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]{2}-\d{2})))$` - [veja](https://regex101.com/r/0eqtXE/3/). Outro detalhe é que se vc usa as barras, não precisa chamar o construtor de `RegExp`, ou seja, pode ser apenas `var expr = /^(([A-Z]{2}.../`

Comment: @hkotsubo bem visto, editei em conformidade tal como sugeriu